# How to serialize CharSequence in Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is there an existing coder I can use to serialize/deserialize CharSequence objects? Do I need to create a custom coder.

I have a bunch of functions that use CharSequence as inputs and outputs. I want to create a generic Dataflow transform that I can use to turn this functions into DoFns.

Comment: I created a custom coder based on StringUtf8Coder; [CharSequenceCoder](https://gist.github.com/jlewi/f01c6ac50cd2d8a7b879). I think this is working but can't be 100% sure yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My custom coder [CharSequenceCoder](https://gist.github.com/jlewi/f01c6ac50cd2d8a7b879) worked.

This coder is based on StringUtf8Coder. The changes I made were

- Change the base class to AtomicCoder<CharSequence>
- Add a couple of conversions from CharSequence to String